# Nginx - remove HTTP Header from response

Tags: nginx, http, http-headers

**Hey guys.**
I have the following question:

**Is it possible to remove or change the value of a header that was added a few lines earlier?**

Here is the whole scenario:

### Setup

#### my-website.com.conf

```
...
server {
    ...
    # security
    include security.conf;
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    ...
}
...
```

#### security.conf

```
# security headers
add_header X-XSS-Protection          "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options    "nosniff" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy           "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
add_header Permissions-Policy        "interest-cohort=()" always;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

# . files
location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}
```

### The problem

In `my-website.com.conf` I want to either completely remove or change the value of the the `Content-Security-Policy`-header that was added in `security.conf`.
*Specificaly the part with `frame-ansestors 'self';` needs to be changed/removed because I want to be able to embed my website in an `<iframe>`.*

The `security.conf` file is included in several other site-configurations so i would rather prefer to leave it as it is.

### What I already tried

I tried changing the following but neither of this changes gave me the result I wanted.

#### my-website.com.conf

```
...
server {
    ...
    # security
    include security.conf;

    # 1. Add header again with the correct value:
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';" always;
    # Result: The header is set but this doesn't remove the original one, which means that
    #         now there are two headers that are contradicting each other which doesn't solve the problem.

    # 2. using proxy_hide_header
    proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;
    # Result: Does literally nothing (I assume this only works in combination with proxy_pass)

    # 3. using more_clear_headers (from headers-more-nginx-module)
    more_clear_headers Content-Security-Policy;
    # Result: Also does literally nothing
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
...
```

### The question

So now again the question:

- Is it possible to remove or change the value of a header that was added a few lines earlier?
- If YES: HOW?
- If NO: Why? Is it a technical issue? Has it something to do with security? Or is this just not implemented?

Sorry for my poor english and thanks in advance :)

Edit:
The whole setup runs on Ubuntu 22.04 and Nginx is in Version 1.18.0

Comment: Remove the `include security.conf;` and add the customized directives directly to the `server{}` block.